# What kind of ready to use *Software Library* would be suitable for UI in a c++ program like Prusa Slicer?

Tags: c++, gui, gui-builder

I've been using slicers for 3D printing for a while and I want to learn in a bit more detail the "inner workings" by making a super simple slicer of my own.

Naturally, I decided to take a look at the source of one of the more popular slicers - Prusa Slicer. On the Github page, the language summary says there is c++ as the primary language. This leads me to believe the most important code, the one that does the slicing, is written in c++.

This brings me to my question, up to now I've written in c++, but only console applications. What is the best, or recommended way to make a c++ program that has a GUI for example Prusa Slicer?

I would like a suggestion for a ready to use Software Product (library) that can be used to create UI using C++.

(Note) I am looking for opinions because I'm looking for a place to start my research for libraries that are suitable. I'm a complete beginner and just looking for people that have already tackled this problem.

Comment: Well, when you first asked it was for a how-to. Thanks to your rephrasing, it now fits here. Though your flag is a bit… well, never mind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prusa Slicer application that you mention seems to use [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) for its UI.

But you will find plenty more if you do a web search for "C++ GUI library" for example, among which [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) or [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/)  are only the most popular ones.